# Are functions in C/C++ headers a no-go?

Tags: c++, header, coding-style, project-structure

I'm working on a very tiny piece of C/C++ source code. The program reads input values from stdin, processes them with an algorithm and writes the results to stdout.

I would just implement all that in a single file, but I also want test cases for the algorithm (not the input/output reading), so I have the following files in my project:

- main.cpp
- sort.hpp
- sort_test.cpp

I implement the algorithm in sort.hpp right away, no sort.cpp. It's rather short and doesn't have any dependencies.

Would you say that, in some cases, functions defined in headers are okay, even if they are sophisticated algorithms and not just simple accessors/mutators? Or is there a reason I should avoid this? When should I move code from header to source file?

Comment: Probably better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. I'd say that any implementation that's longer than a line of code should be in the .cpp file. It might be a bit better to include the declaration in the .cpp file than then implementation in the .hpp file!

Comment: @James: what, why? I don't see why it'd be a better fit on Programmers.SE

Comment: For your test code (`sort_test.cpp`), you might consider including `sort.cpp` directly so you can test its internal functions.

Comment: What's with all that "inline"? Didn't have to do that, works fine. They are just free functions, no class, no namespace, no nothing. Only one cpp file in the project uses it though. (main.cpp for the program, sort_test.cpp for the test case)

Comment: Guess I'll just make it inline. Not looking forward to a weird compiler error as soon as I use that from more than one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority of the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries are header-only, so I'd say: Yes, this is an established and accepted practice. Just don't forget to `inline`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Boost. They do indeed write 90% of their code in headers, it seems :)

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with having functions in header files, as long as you understand the tradeoff. Putting them in a header file means they'll have to be compiled (and recompiled) in any translation unit that includes the header. (and they have to be declared `inline`, or you will get linker errors.)

In projects with many translation units, that may add up to a noticeable slowdown in compile times, if you do it a lot.

On the other hand, it ensures that the function definition is visible everywhere the function is called -- and that means that it can be trivially inlined, so the resulting program may run faster.

And finally, with function templates, you typically have no realistic alternative. The definition *must* be visible at the call site, and the only practical way to achieve that is to put it in a header.

A final consideration is that header-only libraries are easier to deploy and use. You don't need to link against anything, you don't have to worry about ABI's or anything else. You just add the headers to your project, include them and off you go.

Quite a few popular libraries use a header-only strategy.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to put any function in the header as long as it's `inline`. Things such as functions defined inside `class { }` and templates are implicitly `inline`.

If the resulting application becomes too large, then optimize the code size. Optimizing before there is a problem is an anti-pattern, especially when there is a benefit to doing it "your way," and the fix is as simple as moving from one file to another and erasing `inline`.

Of course, if you want to distribute the code as a library, then deciding between a header, static library, or dynamic library binary is an important decision affecting the users.

Answer (score 1):

When you put functions in headers you have to make sure to declare them `inline`. This is required to avoid a duplicate definition warning when more than one .cpp file include that header file. Generally you should only put small functions inside header files because it will be compiled for each cpp file that includes the header which will slow down compilation time and also results in code bloat; a larger executable file.

Answer (score 0):

That really is a stile choice.  But putting it in the header does mean that it will be inline code rather than a function.  If you wanted that same functionality, you could use the inline keyword:

```
inline int max(int a, int b)
{
  return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

Comment: Depends what you mean by "inline code". This does not mean that the code will be actually "inlined" unless the compiler decides that is useful and that will happen if the code is in the header or the source.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you should avoid this in general (for non inline functions) is because multiple source files will be including your header, creating linker errors.
It doesn't matter if you have a pramga once or similar trick - the duplication will show up if you have more than one compilation unit (e.g. cpp files) including the same header.

Comment: This error can be removed by using the keyword "inline". This indicates to the linker that there may be multiple versions of the function and it should only keep one.

Comment: even with the function declaration if its included in multiple time without prama once it will be creating linker errors

Comment: @martin: this is why I specify for-non inline functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to inline the function, it MUST be in the header else it can't get inlined.

If you publish a header with your libraries and the header has some sort of implementation in it, you can be sure that after a few years if you change the implementation and it doesn't work exactly the same way as it did before, some peoples code will break since thay will have come to rely on the implementation they saw in the header. Yeah i know one should not do it but many people do look in header for the implementation and other behaviour they can exploit/use in a not intended way to overcome some problem they are having.

If you are planning to use templates then you have no choice but to put it all in header. (this might not be necessary if you compiler supports export templates but there is only 1 i know of).

Comment: Thats not true. Modern compilers can inline code from other translation units.

Answer (score 0):

Its ok to have the implementation in the header. It depends on what you need. If you separate the definition to a different file then the compiler will create symbols with external linkage if you dont want that you can define the functions inside the header itself. But you would be wasting some amount of memory for the code segment. If you include this header file in two different files then both files codes segment will have this function definition.

If other header file is going to have a function with similar name then its going to be a problem. Then you have to use inline.

Comment: It will waste space be being in multiple object files. But the linker will remove all but one occurrence when the application/dll is linked (unless you declare the function as static).